# Mysql complex nested view values

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery, sql-view

I put these values in a table

mytable

```
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| field1           | field2              |field3           | 
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 1                | 10                  |         0       |
| 1                | 20                  |         0       |
| 2                | 100                 |         0       |
| 2                | 200                 |         0       |
| 3                |                     |         1       |
| 3                |                     |         2       |
| 4                |                     |         3       |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------|
```

I would like to create a view that allows me to have this result

**myview desired result**

```
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| field1           | field2              |field3           | 
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 1                | 10                  |         0       |
| 1                | 20                  |         0       |
| 2                | 100                 |         0       |
| 2                | 200                 |         0       |
| 3                | 30                  |         1       |
| 3                | 300                 |         2       |
| 4                | 330                 |         3       |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------|
```

```
30  is the sum of field2 where field1=1 (value of field3)
300 is the sum of field2 where field1=2 (value of field3)
330 is the sum of field2 where field1=3 (value of field3)
```

**how do i get the values 30,300 and 330?**

Comment: Precise MySQL version?

Comment: I would avoid constructing a view for this. It probably serves no useful purpose.

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL 8+ use

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT field1, field2, field3
         FROM mytable
         WHERE field2 IS NOT NULL
       UNION ALL
         SELECT mytable.field1, cte.field2, mytable.field3
         FROM cte
         JOIN mytable ON cte.field1 = mytable.field3 )
SELECT field1, SUM(field2) field2, field3
FROM cte
GROUP BY field1, field3, CASE WHEN field3 = 0 THEN RAND() ELSE field3 END;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9170503161aa3c57803cb735e93316e5)